# Elasticsearch get _parent source fields from child document

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've created parent/child relation in Elasticsearch.

- User - parent
- Image - child

I do filtering thousands of images, small example of code

```
$query = array(
          'query_string' => array(
                    'query' => $queryParams['category'],
                    'default_operator' => 'AND',
                    'default_field' => 'allParentCategories',
          )
);

$reqParams['body'] = array(
        'query' => array(
            'filtered' => array(
                'query' => $query,
                'filter' => array(
                    'bool' => array(
                        'must' => $filtersArray,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
);
```

this is what i'm getting as a result

```
array (size=8)
      '_index' => string 'images-15' (length=9)
      '_type' => string 'image' (length=5)
      '_id' => string '48026' (length=5)
      '_score' => null
      '_routing' => string '2' (length=1)
      '_parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      '_source' => 
        array (size=15)
          'thumb' => string 'fasdfas' (length=52)
          'author' => 
            array (size=6)
              'firstName' => string 'asdfas' (length=3)
              'lastName' => string 'asdf' (length=3)
              'fullName' => string 'asdfas' (length=7)
              'id' => string '2' (length=1)
              'picture' => null
              'username' => string 'asdfa' (length=6)
          'downloadURL' => string 'asdfasd' (length=87)
          'creationDate' => string '2016-07-15 11:20:12' (length=19)
          'tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
              'size' => 
            array (size=2)
              'bytes' => int 735025
              'formatted' => string '717.8 KB' (length=8)
          'downloads' => int 0
          'added_by' => int 2
          'width' => int 900
          'is_icon' => boolean false
          'is_vector' => boolean false
          'id' => int 48026
          'views' => int 0
          'height' => int 900
          'likes' => int 1
      'sort' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1468581612000
          1 => int 48026
```

I've already tried thing like this:

```
$reqParams['body'] = array(
        'query' => array(
            'has_parent' => [
                'parent_type' => 'user',
                'query' => [
                    'match_all' => []
                ],
                'inner_hits' => [
                   '_source' => ['*']
                ]
            ],
        )
);
```

1. In first case I can get just parent ID which is useless for my
   purposes.
2. In second case I have access to all _source fields of parent document
   but I can't do filtration.

What I need it's get access to _parent _source fields and keep images filtration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. In that way I have access to parent fields and keeps my search results as before.
[image]